# Portable method for getting ACL perms from acl_permset_t

Tags: c, permissions, posix, acl

The POSIX.1e (draft) standard defines a number of functions for working with ACLs (defined in `sys/acl.h` regardless of platform). See the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl) for an overview of the standard. One critical function, `acl_get_perm`, which queries to see whether an `acl_permset_t` has a particular permission (`acl_permset_t` is meant to be an opaque type) is only defined as a Linux-specific extension. Some sources (see [here](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2001-April/013025.html) for example) suggest that `acl_get_perm`, or its non-portable variant, `acl_get_perm_np`, is defined on other systems, even though the standard doesn't require it.

- Is there a portable way to query an `acl_permset_t` for a given permission?

All of the code I've found online so far does one of the following:

- Skirts the issue by using the `acl_to_text` function, defined in `libacl`, to get a text representation of the ACL directly, without having to inspect the permissions directly (see, for example, Darwin's [implementation of getfacl](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/getfacl/getfacl.c.html))
- Skirts the issue by only setting permissions, not getting them (see, for example, Darwin's [implementation of setfacl](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/setfacl/))
- Checks at configuration time to see whether one of the `acl_get_perm` variants is defined, and otherwise concludes that POSIX ACLs are not supported (see, for example, Darwin's [bsdtar_platform.h](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/ports/archivers/libarchive/work/libarchive-2.3.5/tar/bsdtar_platform.h))

None of these approaches is desirable. What I'd really like is a way that I can use the POSIX-compliant portion of `libacl` to query permissions myself without having to rely on system-specific extensions. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Note that POSIX.1e is not strictly a standard — it was never formally ratified.  That makes it difficult to look for a standard-compliant solution because there is only a de facto standard (at best) to be compliant with.  As a result, each system that implements it does it slightly differently, with the consequences that you've identified.  'Tis a pity, but 'tis also the way it goes.  You will have to write somewhat platform-specific code to do the job.

Comment: I was afraid of that...

Comment: On a related note, is it safe to assume that, for a given system, the library will be stable? What I'd like to do is have code that's specific to a particular platform/architecture pair (ie, linux/amd64) and know that it will always work. Would that be a reasonable approach, or would it be better for me to have lots of ifdef guards dependent on the presence or absence of certain functions, as opposed to just dependent on the system being compiled for?

Comment: (I'm writing Go that will interface with libacl, and in Go it's much more natural to have platform-specific code as opposed to using ifdef guards in the embedded C I'm compiling)

Comment: The general rules for upwards compatibility apply — most systems will try to keep old code running (with or without recompilation) across most upgrades. Consequently, what works for one particular hardware and o/s combination will usually work for subsequent versions (but not necessarily prior versions) of the same o/s on the same hardware. Indeed, the 'hardware' component is usually not significant for this level of code; the operations of ACLs are not hardware dependent but basically only o/s dependent. You can code reasonably confidently to the API on some platform and expect that to work.

Comment: OK, sounds good. And out of curiosity, since I'm not too familiar with how these things are implemented under the hood, what would happen if I tried to run my program on a system that didn't support the function calls I was making? Put another way: on platforms that support it, does libacl exist as a library which programs dynamically link against? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: If your program is linked with `libacl.so` but someone tries to run it on a platform without `libacl.so`, it will fail to start with an error about the library not being found.